# Terminal Server 2008 not issuing Volume device CAL's

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server, licensing

We've a lot of Volume Licences left, but the License Server apparantly
doesn't use them. Instead it issues Temporary Per Device CAL's. Which is a bit odd off course...

There are two licensing servers installed on terminal servers, not on a domain controller (these are pushed by SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\LicenseServers registry setting)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from the screenshot, but make sure that the Temporary TS CALs are 'Per Device' and not 'Per User', and that the Terminal Server itself is configure as Per Device.

If your TS server is set to Per User, and the temporary licenses are the only Per User licenses, that would explain why users are not getting full licenses.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up your licensing terms. Do you have Windows Server 2008 Terminal Services CAL's installed on your TS license server? Is the license server activated?

Comment: Yes, there are CAL's installed and the license server is activated.

Comment: Have you run the "Review Configuration" from TS License Manager?

Comment: Yes, I only get the message 'not installed on a domain controller', but this should not be a problem.